# React Navigator Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer? - React native EXPO ERROR

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, jsx, react-navigation

I tried to made a navegation component, Here is the full output when the error pops: :

"This error is located at:
in LoginScreen (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException

- ... 7 more stack frames from framework internals "

I tried with the documentation in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/ and i tried with other tutorials, but i did not have any solution yet.

btw, i got other messages as "'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8006". That file was created by using expo, i have not touched it yet.

logedin.js

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler" ;
import Navegar from "./Navigation";

export default function Loggedin () {
    return ( 
        <Navegar/>



    )
}
```

navigation.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Feed from "./feed";

function Navegar() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

export default Navegar;
```

```
feed.js
import {SafeAreaView, Text, View} from "react-native";

export default function Feed() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHkkHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Please i need help with this, it's for my grades :((

I need to be able to use a navigation bar with expo

I tried to made a navegation component, but i just got this "Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?"

I tried with the documentation in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/ and i tried with other tutorials, but i did not have any solution yet.

btw, i got other messages as "'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8006". That file was created by using expo, i have not touched it yet.

Comment: Which component is generating the error?  It all looks fine, but where is your app being created?  You are showing where the LoggedIn is called, but it must exist somewhere inside of the app itself.  Can you show that?